How to keep mixamo animation only in some parts like hands, feet or another parts?
When I imported mixamo animation, how to keep mixamo animation only in some parts like hands, feet or another parts? And remove all the other parts animation.

You can delete specific keyframes for a bone in the Timeline to stop a part of your model moving but that's going to cause problems because its overall location is going to change as the rest of the model moves. So to answer your question the answer has to be "No"!

Thank you for the help!
